# Accessing R source code files

Tags: r

I've new to R and I've successfully install a package. I would like to examine the source code of this package. I understand that I can view the source of a given function by just typing the name of the function at the prompt. How can I get access to the source code files such that I can browse it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Spacedman wrote under R-help list, *why so shy about mentioning the package?*.

Go to CRAN page for the package and just download the source directly and extract the files. All R files will be under `R` directory and any `C` files will be under `src` directory.

Answer (score 3):

It is easiest to just download the source package from CRAN, extract the `tar.gz` file (e.g. using [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or `tar`), browse to the `/R` subfolder and open the file that contains the code. If you are not really sure where a particular function is located, you can use a tool like `grep` to look for it, e.g.:

```
grep spam_function *
```

if you are looking for `spam_function`.